# ldapsearch to exclude disabled users from the user list

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I am using FreeIPA for Identity access management, i have to provide an active user list (audit requirement). I am using a ldapsearch but i am getting all the user (active+disabled) in the list. Kindly help me to get a user list which exclude disabled users from the list.

Query used:
ldapsearch  -h   -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -D "uid=,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com"  -W -x "uid" "gecos" "ntUserLastLogon" "displayName" "employeeType=ENABLED"

Comment: i can help you rewrite your query (by using another search filter) to just display active users, but for that i need the user attributes, can you please show me an example of a inactive user ? (it should have a field like UserActive or something), as your employeetype=enabled does not seem to work

Comment: Hi, The user have full admin Access :<ID>, users, accounts, ipa.net
dn: uid
ntUserLastLogon:
krbExtraData: 
krbPasswordExpiration: 
krbLastPwdChange: 
krbLastSuccessfulAuth: 
ipaSshPubKey:
mepManagedEntry: cn=<ID>
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalperson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: ipaSshGroupOfPubKeys
objectClass: mepOriginEntry
ntUserDeleteAccount: true
sn: <SN>
givenName: <Name>
cn: <Name>
ntUserCodePage: 0
ntUserAcctExpires: 
ntUserDomainId: <ID>
ntUniqueId: 
uid: <ID>
krbPrincipalName: <ID>@IPA.NET

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [olivierg](https://serverfault.com/users/404882/olivierg) for answer, it saved my day!
But there is one minor correction from my side.
If you need to exclude disabled users from the ldapsearch returned from freeipa I would recommend to use syntax provided below:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://freeipa.example.com -x -W -D "uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com" -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(&(objectClass=person)(!(nsaccountlock=TRUE))(memberOf=cn=pgsql_writers,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com))" cn
```

This query will return pgsql_writers group members (persons only).

Answer (score 1):

Try with `"(nsaccountlock=TRUE)"` instead of `"employeetype=enabled"`